# navigation menu based on user level

Tags: php, menu, mysqli

Hi i am creating a navigation system based on user level. The code i made doen't show any error but its not displaying the menu. I dont know where i went wrong. I googled for this kind of menu but i couldn't find any solution. Can anyone sort the mistake i have made? Or tell me if there is anyother way to do it?

Here is my code.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
</head>
    <body>

<!--database connection-->

<?php
//error_reporting(0);
'session_start()';
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
if($con->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Sorry, We\'re experiencing some connection problems.');
}
?>

<!--functions-->

<?php
    function loggedin(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
?>


<!--titlebar-->

<div>
    <?php
        if(loggedin()){
            $my_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
            $log=$con->prepare("SELECT username,user_level FROM users WHERE user_id='$my_id'");
            $log->execute;
            $log->bind_result($username, $user_level,$my_id);
            $log->store_result;
            if($log->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row
            {
                if($user_level=='a'){?>
                    <a href = 'index.php'>Home</a>
                    <a href = 'admin.php'>Admin</a>
                    <a href = 'index.php'>Log Out</a>
                <?php
                }if($user_level=='m'){?>
                    <a href = 'index.php'>Home</a>
                    <a href = 'profile.php'>Profile</a>
                    <a href = 'index.php'>Log Out</a>
                <?php
                }else{?>
                    <a href = 'index.php'>Home</a>
                    <a href = 'login.php'>Login</a>
                    <a href = 'register.php'>Register</a>
            <?php
            }
        }
        }
    ?>

</div>
Index
</body>
</html>
```

I have used the same method for my login page which is working fine. This is my login page code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>LOGIN</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'connect.php';?>
<?php include 'functions.php';?>
<?php include 'titlebar.php';?>

<h3>LOGIN HERE:</h3>
<form action ="" method="post">

User Name:<br/>
<input type='text' name='username' />
<br/><br/>
Password:<br/>
<input type='password' name='password' />
<br/><br/>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='login'>
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);


    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT user_id, username, password, status FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $password, $status);
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows == 1)  //To check if the row exists
        {
            if($stmt->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row
            {
               if ($status == 'd') {
                   echo "YOUR account has been DEACTIVATED.";
                   exit();
               } 
               if ($status == 'b') {
                   echo "YOUR account has been BANNED.";
                   exit();
               } 
               if ($status == 'n') {
                   echo "YOUR account has NOT YET BEEN ACTIVATED.";
                   exit();
               } 
               else {
                   $_SESSION['Logged'] = 1;
                   $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                   echo 'Success!';
                   exit();
               }
           }

    }
    else {
        echo "INVALID USERNAME/PASSWORD Combination!";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
else 
{   

}
$con->close();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appretiated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like loggedin() function doesn't work

1. Have you already logged in?
2. 'session_start'; ===== > Have you ment here session_start() ? (If so don't forget to start your session before any output. For instance, just before "html" tag used)

UPD:

1. You should be logged in.
2. You have to start your session
3. There are some other problem dealing with mysqli object and statement.

I've edited this code to make it work and put some comments into it.
Take a look here

http://pastebin.com/Za1V0VES

Comment: no i have not loggedin but anyways it should the menu for register and login but its not showing. and that session was a typo

Comment: Of course it won't show any menu because statement         if(loggedin()){...} wil never return TRUE for unlogged user. If we talk about working login page then you'd better show the source of included files

Comment: those included files are in the first code section on this page

Comment: Ok just try some simple steps:

1. Remove string 'session_start'; and at the top of the page write something like <?php session_start();?>
2. You SHOULD be logged in otherwise your loggedin() function won't return TRUE statement => you won't get menu printing section acces => you couldn't make a query because $my_id=$_SESSION['user_id']; wil give you empty string.
3. Just for proving you can "emulate" user logging with something like this: $_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function loggedin() in F:\XAMPP\htdocs\login\titlebar.php on line 3

Comment: Now it seems like you've broken your page tags or whatever. Could you please put your new code somewhere to pastbin? For example  http://pastebin.com/Sbv8rUGm

Comment: http://pastebin.com/i2VkXezf  Now the error is gone but when i remove the if section and have only the home login register it shows the menu. I think the problem is somewhere around the function.

Comment: 1. You haven't moved 'session_start()'; at the top without quotes. Now it's stil just a STRING; Problem is not in the function, problem is that you haven't LOGGED IN. Take a look at my new FULL answer

Comment: ok if i am not logged in it should show the menu for login. why is it not showing???

Comment: It's not showing because your menu printing is under the if (loggedin()) statement. Add ELSE block there and move your Home-Login-Register menu there. Here is the example http://pastebin.com/tQgqWrvV

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Here is how i have understood your question: you need a certain a number of links in your navigation to display based on user level: lets if admin is logged in then **these** links should display or if frontdesk is logged in then **those** links should display.

If this is so then here is how you do it rather how i did it:

```
<?php
//Start session
    session_start();

    //Check whether the session variable SESS_MEMBER_ID is present or not
    if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) || (trim($_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']) == '')) {
        header("location: index.php");
        exit();
    } 

if($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']=="admin"){

 /*Your Links go here*/

 }

if($_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME']=="frontdesk"){

/*Your links go here*/

}?>
```

Here is my login.php

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();

    //Connect to mysql server
    /* Database connection goes here*/

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $login = clean($_POST['user']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);

    //Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$login' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['position'];
            session_write_close();
            header("location: home_admin.php");
            exit();

        }else {
            //Login failed
            header("location: admin_index.php");
            exit();
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using echo

```
<!--titlebar-->
<div>
<?php
    if(loggedin()){
        $my_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
        $log=$con->prepare("SELECT username,user_level FROM users WHERE user_id='$my_id'");
        $log->execute;
        $log->bind_result($username, $user_level,$my_id);
        $log->store_result;
        if($log->fetch()) //fetching the contents of the row
        {
            if($user_level=='a'){
                echo "
                 <a href = 'index.php'>Home</a>
                 <a href = 'admin.php'>Admin</a>
                 <a href = 'index.php'>Log Out</a>
                ";
            }if($user_level=='m'){
                echo "
                 <a href = 'index.php'>Home</a>
                 <a href = 'profile.php'>Profile</a>
                 <a href = 'index.php'>Log Out</a>
                ";
            }else{
                echo "
                 <a href = 'index.php'>Home</a>
                 <a href = 'login.php'>Login</a>
                 <a href = 'register.php'>Register</a>
                ";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```